# How can I handle nested forms in react-final-form?

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I intend to make certain fields editable via a "popup" portal, where the popup itself is managed by a form. When you "submit" the nested form, the field updates. - https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/276

The issue I'm getting into is that the onSubmitCustom (inner form) triggers for both the onSubmit for the inner form and the onSubmit for the outer form.

How can I get nested forms to work in react-final-form?

As a workaround, if I had a way to capture the form id that actually submitted the form, I could return false on the outer form's onSubmit when the onSubmitCustom (inner form) is triggered. But I have yet to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Looks like this was fixed very shortly after my post. 
- [Fix support for nested forms by calling stopPropagation #289](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/pull/289)

Comment: And you've tried v3.6.3?

Comment: I have tried 3.6.3 (and 3.6.4) and it unfortunately didn't fix my particular issue. I may be doing something wrong but basically I have two forms, one nested within the other. When I submit the inner form, both onSubmit functions are being called.

Comment: In a simpler project it's working - See [https://codesandbox.io/s/p7p6lx24xq](https://codesandbox.io/s/p7p6lx24xq). I'll have to revisit my other project. Thank you.

Comment: What seems to be different in my particular case is that I add the component via ReactDOM.render(). Another thing I noticed was that the formRenderProps were not reflecting the nested form, submitting was always false, even when it should have been true. Only after making my onSubmit() async using async/await did I start getting the proper formRenderProps values for the nested form, but it still triggers the outer form's onSubmit() when it shouldn't.